# Can getpivotdata be used with an OR condition?

Tags: excel-formula, formula

I am building a Compare worksheet, pulling "Amounts" from two pivots.  The Amounts are retrieved based on conditions. I need the Amount based on an OR statement for one of the conditions and I am stuck in the formula.  I've been using getpivotdata, but I'm not finding how to get an OR condition in.

Below formula is working for the 2 main criteria (NameID and GRP-CODE).. but I need to layer in an OR condition for "Tax-Type"=P.
Essentially: Get Amount if NameID=A2, GRP-CODE=OTH OR TAX-TYPE=P, otherwise "".

```
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of HPACFF-AMT",SMSBenDetail!$J$4:J$10000,"NameID-BenCode",$A2,"GRP-CODE","OTH"),"")
```

I'm not against changing up my formula, but GetPivot is so easy to troubleshoot I was trying to stick with it.  Thoughts?